# Is there an equivalent for .NET's Debugger.Launch() for python?

Tags: python, debugging

I'd like to be able to launch and attach a debugger at a specific point in some python 3.6 code without having to be attached to it from the program start. .NET has this via [Debugger.Launch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netframework-4.7.2), where when that statement is hit I am prompted to attach a debugger.

Is there something like this for Python 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

use above statement to debug command code,step in(s), step out(o),next(n), continue(c)  and read official documentation python with pdb it will nice core dubugger of python 2 and python3

Comment: This is close enough to be the answer, but I was looking to choose the debugger at the time the statement was executed.  I dont think I would call any console based debugger "nice" by today's standards, but it is serviceable.

Comment: one and half year of my experienced its best to debug python with pdb debugger as console its nice and easily debug, you will also enjoying debugging